Windows 11 snap windows group not coming back top using ALT + TAB after using fullscreen on Youtube video on browser. How to fix?
I have a browser window and a private browser window open side by side using snap assist on Windows 11. Using ALT+TAB I can cycle other windows and return the snap group back on top.
The issues is that if I play a Youtube video on the browser in fullscreen, exit fullscreen, bring some other window to the top then try bringing the browser group back to the top it doesn't come back.
The window or windows which are brought to the top stay on top even after cycling ALT+TAB to bring the browser windows to the top.
I have to use the mouse and click both windows for them to come back on top and the only way to get it working again is to repeat the snap layout procedure for the windows. The two browser windows are just an example. Tried it with different windows and the same issue occurs.

It's not browser related. Tried it with Firefox and Brave. Same issue on both.
